# Infinite series identities in search of a proof

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This comes in relation to the [Fishburn numbers](https://oeis.org/A022493).

I stumbled on the following relation for which I ask a proof if true.

> Let $Q_i(z):=1-(1-t)^{i-1}(1-zt)$.  Then
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)zt}{(1-zt)^{n+1}}\prod_{i=1}^nQ_i(1)=
> \sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\sum_{j=2}^m\prod_{i=1,\, i\neq j}^mQ_i(z) -
> \sum_{m=2}^{\infty}(m-1)\prod_{i=1}^mQ_i(z).$$